# Nested repeater control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a nested repeater control with multiple views. Here the parent repeater is bound to a datatable. When we click on the div in parent repeater, child repeaters will be displayed in a dropdown box. But I'm getting same instance of child repeaters in all views of parent repeater. Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row row-border pb-1 pt-1 border-bottom border-dark dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <asp:Label ID="LabelDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Test 1"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Test 2"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Test 3"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Test 4"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Header 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-md-12">
                                 <%# Container.DataItem?.ToString() ?? string.Empty%>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-md-12">
                                 <%# Container.DataItem?.ToString() ?? string.Empty%>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    var Temp1= new List<string>();
    var Temp2= new List<string>();
    ...

    Repeater Rptr2 = (e.Item.FindControl("Repeater2") as Repeater);
    Repeater Rptr3 = (e.Item.FindControl("Repeater3") as Repeater);
    Rptr2.DataSource = Temp1;
    Rptr3.DataSource = Temp2;
    Rptr2.DataBind();
    Rptr3.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: How do you confirm that you are getting the same repeater? How many items you have in parent repeater? All the child repeaters are not populated?

Comment: While debugging i found that, the values are correctly binding to child repeaters. but when i click on div in parent repeater , the first instance is always showing in the dropdown. The below javascript i'm using to show the dropdown. $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        });

Comment: Also I have checked in 'view page source' option, and the data is coming correctly there.